# Javascript button wont work or show

Tags: php, html

I have been trying for few hours now to try and get this working. However, the code is working fine but the second button just does not show on my website. Could you please help?

```html
echo "<td><input class=button_normal type=button value=Google Renter onclick=window.window.open(href='https://www.google.co.uk/')"; 
echo "<input class=button_normal type=button value=Yahoo onclick=window.window.open(href='https://www.yahoo.co.uk')</td>";
```

Comment: Is this PHP? `echo` is not valid Javascript

Comment: is it normal window.window.open ???

Comment: I am trying to put two buttons in the same row, however once user clicks on the button it opens the button in a new tab, the second button is not working, please advise.

Comment: the first button shows and once clicked it opens the webpage in a new tab, whreas the seocnd just does not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added quotations to onclick, value and class. You also forgot to close the input tag.

```
echo "<td><input class='button_normal' type='button' value='Google Renter' onclick='window.window.open.href=\'https://www.google.co.uk/\''/>"; 
echo "<input class='button_normal' type='button' value='Yahoo' onclick='window.location.href=\'https://www.yahoo.co.uk\''/></td>";
```

What I suggest is this:

```
<script>
function goToYahoo() {
window.open('https://www.yahoo.co.uk');
} 
function goToGoogle() {
window.open('https://www.google.co.uk');
}
</script>
<?php

    echo "<td><input class='button_normal' type='button' value='Google Renter' onclick='goToGoogle()'/>"; 
    echo "<input class='button_normal' type='button' value='Yahoo' onclick='goToYahoo()'/></td>";
?>
```

Comment: Jad I have tried this code however it just does not open up the webpages, when on them.

Comment: @Jad, please change `window.location(href` to `window.location.href` and this should work.

Comment: The link still does not do anything once clicked on the link.

Comment: yhes I have, still the same the button clicks but nothing happens.

Comment: @sam use heredocs in php for better readability, "https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc"  , then you dont need to use two echo statements ..

Comment: if I use this code, it only shows the google button however not the yahoo button. echo "<td><input class=button_normal type=button value=Google onclick=window.window.open(href='https://www.google.co.uk/')"; 
echo "<input class=button_normal type=button value=Yahoo onclick=window.window.open(href='https://www.yahoo.co.uk')</td>";

Comment: EDITED IT ONE LAST TIME. THIS NOW WORKS AND I CAN CONFIRM IT.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is a property not method:

```
window.location(href='https://www.yahoo.co.uk')
```

Should be:

```
window.location.href='https://www.yahoo.co.uk'
```

Comment: it is meant to be window.open not location that was just a mistake I made.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your code you are missing input tag closing "/>"

```
echo <<<"FOOBAR"
  <td>
     <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Google Renter" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/')"/>; 
     <input class="button_normal" type="button" value="Yahoo" onclick="window.open('https://www.yahoo.co.uk')"/>
  </td>    
FOOBAR;
```